# How to get Apache FOP to embed Fonts in a PDF/A-2b

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP v2.6 & trying to generate a PDF/A-2b with one of the Base-14 Fonts Embedded.

I'm getting an org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFConformanceException:

> "For PDF/A-2b, all fonts, even the base 14 fonts, have to be embedded!
> Offending font: /Helvetica"

Here's what I think is the relevant snippet of Code:

Any ideas what might be missing?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import org.apache.fop.Version;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.fop.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.fop.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PdfBuilder {

    private static final Logger     LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdfBuilder.class);

    private static final FopFactory FOP_FACTORY;
    /**/    static {
        final var fopConfigXml =
            """
                <fop version="1.0">
                    <renderers>
                        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
                            <fonts>
                                <auto-detect/>
                            </fonts>
                        </renderer>
                    </renderers>
                </fop>
            """;

        final     var fopFactoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI());
        try {
            final var fopConfigStream   = new ByteArrayInputStream(fopConfigXml.getBytes());
            final var fopConfig         = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder().build(fopConfigStream);

            fopFactoryBuilder.setConfiguration(fopConfig);

            LOG.info ("FOP Config.:"       + " fopVersion={} xml.:{}{}", Version.getVersion(), "\n", fopConfigXml);
        }
        catch (final ConfigurationException e) {
            LOG.error("FOP Config Error.:" + " fopVersion={} xml.:{}{}", Version.getVersion(), "\n", fopConfigXml, e);
        }
        FOP_FACTORY = fopFactoryBuilder.build();
    }

    public byte[] generatePDFfromFO(final byte[] bytesFO) throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException {

        final var foUserAgent = FOP_FACTORY.newFOUserAgent();
        /**/      foUserAgent.getRendererOptions().put("pdf-a-mode", "PDF/A-2b");
        :
        :
        :
        :
        return pdfBytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hitherto, I had assumed the Fonts were somehow included in Apache FOP.
That is ***not*** the case
Apache FOP contains *Metadata*, describing the Fonts, which is used to *Layout* the PDF.

To include Fonts, as mandated for PDF/A, you have to *supply* them.
See example, below.

But that still doesn't solve the problem:
even though all Fonts were explicitly mapped to one of the configured Fonts, the
*"For PDF/A-2b, all fonts, even the base 14 fonts, have to be embedded! Offending font: /Helvetica"*
error still occurs.

**It is necessary to explicitly configure the default Font at the root of the Stylesheet.**

I believe that is a Bug in Apache FOP, but never mind, I now have a workaround.

The FOP Config looked something like this:

```
<fop version="1.0">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Helvetica-Regular.ttf"   ><font-triplet name="Helvetica"    style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Helvetica-Italic.ttf"    ><font-triplet name="Helvetica"    style="italic" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Helvetica-Bold.ttf"      ><font-triplet name="Helvetica"    style="normal" weight="bold"  /></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Helvetica-BoldItalic.ttf"><font-triplet name="Helvetica"    style="italic" weight="bold"  /></font>

                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Times-Regular.ttf"       ><font-triplet name="Times"        style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Times-Italic.ttf"        ><font-triplet name="Times"        style="italic" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Times-Bold.ttf"          ><font-triplet name="Times"        style="normal" weight="bold"  /></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Times-BoldItalic.ttf"    ><font-triplet name="Times"        style="italic" weight="bold"  /></font>

                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Courier-Regular.ttf"     ><font-triplet name="Courier"      style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Courier-Italic.ttf"      ><font-triplet name="Courier"      style="italic" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Courier-Bold.ttf"        ><font-triplet name="Courier"      style="normal" weight="bold"  /></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Courier-BoldItalic.ttf"  ><font-triplet name="Courier"      style="italic" weight="bold"  /></font>

                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/Symbol.ttf"              ><font-triplet name="Symbol"       style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
                <font kerning="yes" embed-url="path/ZapfDingbats.ttf"        ><font-triplet name="ZapfDingbats" style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced.: Apache FOP figured out from the Stylesheet, it wanted Helvetica, but although Helvetica in all styles (normal & italic) & weights (normal & bold) was explicitly available, it still threw an exception. And apart from some standard XML api's, the entire Stacktrace is Apache FOP.

Comment: There it says "embedding of defined fonts will not work" ("defined" meaning one of the Base-14 fonts). My understanding is that any font may be embedded, whether it is Base-14 or not. It goes on to say [sic] "each PDF reader must provide this fonts". That is not my understanding: I believe non-embedded fonts are rendered with the best fit, depending on the viewer platform. My Windows 10 PC renders Helvetica as Arial. That PDF/A requires fonts be embedded is an empirical requirement of the "A" (Archive), so no matter when or where, in some future universe, the PDF can be rendered accurately.